Snowflake Kafka connector - Failed to append columns during schema evolution
I am trying to deploy a snowflake-kafka connector (on a kafka connect cluster) to read messages from a kafka topic and write it into a snowflake table. I have enabled schema evolution so that new columns will get added to the table as they come up in the kafka messages. below is my configuration:
{
  "name": "Snowflake_non-prod_204",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "8",
    "topics": "test_topic_204",
    "snowflake.private.key.passphrase": "${asm:snowflake.private.key.passphrasetest}",
    "buffer.flush.time": "60",
    "snowflake.url.name": "hostname:443",
    "snowflake.database.name": "npdb",
    "snowflake.schema.name": "npschema",
    "snowflake.role.name": "role_name",
    "snowflake.ingestion.method": "SNOWPIPE_STREAMING",
    "snowflake.enable.schematization": "TRUE",
    "buffer.count.records": "10000",
    "snowflake.user.name": "np_user",
    "snowflake.private.key": "${asm:snowflake.private.keytest}",
    "snowflake.topic2table.map": "test_topic_204:test_table_204",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "FALSE",
    "buffer.size.bytes": "5000000",
    "snowflake.column.name.mapper": "order-id:order_id, product_sub-code:product_sub_code"
  }
}

after deploying this, I see messages like these in the log:
com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeKafkaConnectorException: [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to append columns\nError Code: 2015\nDetail: Failed to append columns during schema evolution\nMessage: SQL compilation error:\nsyntax error line 1 at position 532 unexpected '-'.

I checked the schema of the Kafka messages and found that there are a couple of columns with - in their name. According to the error message, I figured snowflake doesn't like having - in the column names and hence I tried adding "snowflake.column.name.mapper": "order-id:order_id, product_sub-code:product_sub_code" to the configuration.
But this didn't resolve the issue. I keep seeing the same errors in the log and no data is landing in the table. How can I resolve this?  Any help is appreciated!
